# Un contador de espacios de n frases no me devuelve un resultado correcto

Tags: c

Se trata de un algoritmo que lee n frases, y de esas n frases, imprimirá cuantas palabras hay en cada frase. Compila y me lee las n frases pero a la hora de imprimir los espacios que hay en cada frase, me da un numero muy lejos de lo que busco. Disculpas de antemano, soy muy nuevo en esto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define Max 5

int main()
{
    char oracion[100];
    char oraciones [20][Max];
    int i,h,NdO,k,j,p=0,contEspacios[20];

    printf("¿Cuantas oraciones desea ordenar? ");
    scanf ("%d",&NdO);
    fflush(stdin);
    for(k=0;k<NdO;k++) //Contador oraciones
    { 
        printf("Ingrese la oracion numero %d\n", k+1 );
        gets (oraciones [k]);
    }

    for (i=0;i<NdO;i++){

        for(h=0;h<strlen(oraciones[i]);h++){

            if (oraciones[i][h]== ' ' ){
                contEspacios[p]=contEspacios[p]+1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (j=0;j<NdO;j++)
        printf ("%i",contEspacios [j]);
```

Comment: Es buena costumbre **inicializar las variables**, te ahorras sustos: `contEspacios[20] = { 0 }`. Voto por cerrarla como `error tipográfico`.

Comment: Tanto por el código como por las cabeceras usadas, esta pregunta es [tag:c], no [tag:c++].

Answer (score 0):

Utilizas "p" para acceder a la posición, pero nunca la modificas. Según está te dará el número total de espacios en todas las frases en lugar del número en cada frase.

```
contEspacios[i]=contEspacios[i]+1;
```